# Bakery - Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a program to calculate the amount of flour, eggs, sugar and butter required for making lemon cakes and cupcakes.

```
import math

cupcake = [4, 0.1, 12, 14]
#[Butter, egg, flour, sugar]
lemon = [80, 4.5, 240, 300]
#[Butter, egg, flour, sugar]

cup_in = int(input('How many cupcakes would you like? '))
lem_in = int(input('How much lemon cake would you like? '))

amount_cup = []
amount_cup = [x*cup_in for x in cupcake]

amount_lemon = []
amount_lemon = [(x * lem_in) for x in lemon]

print(amount_cup)
print(amount_lemon)

total = []
total = [x + y for x, y in zip(amount_cup, amount_lemon)]

print(total)

amt_butter = total[0]
amt_egg = total[1]
amt_flour = total[2]
amt_sugar = total[3]


bag_but_large = 0
bag_but_medium = 0
bag_but_small = 0

bag_flr_large = 0
bag_flr_medium = 0
bag_flr_small = 0

bag_egg_large = 0
bag_egg_medium = 0
bag_egg_small = 0

bag_sgr_large = 0
bag_sgr_medium = 0
bag_sgr_small = 0

#Calculates the amount of butter bags needed
while amt_butter > 0:

    if amt_butter > 500:
        amt_butter -= 500
        bag_but_large += 1

    elif amt_butter > 250:
        amt_butter -= 250
        bag_but_medium += 1

    elif amt_butter > 125:
        amt_butter -= 125
        bag_but_small += 1        

    else:
        bag_but_small += 1
        amt_butter = 0

#Flour
while amt_flour > 0:

    if amt_flour > 750:
        amt_flour -= 750
        bag_flr_large += 1        

    elif amt_flour > 500:
        amt_flour -= 500
        bag_flr_medium += 1

    elif amt_flour > 250:
        amt_flour -= 250
        bag_flr_small += 1        

    else:
        bag_flr_small += 1
        amt_flour = 0

#Egg
    while amt_egg > 0:

        if amt_egg > 12:
            amt_egg -= 12
            bag_egg_large += 1            

        elif amt_egg > 10:
            amt_egg -= 10
            bag_egg_medium += 1

        elif amt_egg > 6:
            amt_egg -= 6
            bag_egg_small += 1

        else:
            bag_egg_small += 1
            amt_egg = 0

#Sugar
while amt_sugar > 0:

        if amt_sugar > 600:
            amt_sugar -= 600
            bag_sgr_large += 1

        elif amt_sugar > 400:
            amt_sugar -= 400
            bag_sgr_medium += 1

        elif amt_sugar > 200:
            amt_sugar -= 200
            bag_sgr_small += 1

        else:
            bag_sgr_small += 1
            amt_sugar = 0

print("*" * 80)
print("Purchases needed: ")
print(bag_but_large, "large bags of butter needed.")
print(bag_but_medium, "medium bags of butter needed.")
print(bag_but_small, "small bags of butter needed.")
print("*" * 80)
print(bag_flr_large, "large bags of flour needed.")
print(bag_flr_medium, "medium bags of flour needed.")
print(bag_flr_small, "small bags of flour needed.")
print("*" * 80)
print(bag_sgr_large, "large bags of sugar needed.")
print(bag_sgr_medium, "medium bags of sugar needed.")
print(bag_sgr_small, "small bags of sugar needed.")
print("*" * 80)
print(bag_egg_large, "large boxes of eggs needed.")
print(bag_egg_medium, "medium boxes of eggs needed.")
print(bag_egg_small, "small boxes of eggs needed.")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use functions and better datatypes.

You need to know how many; butter, egg, flour and sugar, bags you need, which come in large, medium and small sizes.
And so wrote the same while loop four times.
Which is perfect for a function!

Instead you should make a function if we keep it simple and have it work the way you have it now,
then you can use a function like `trickle_groups(amount: int, large: int, medium: int, small: int) -> tuple<int, int, int>`.
Which would get you the function:

```
def trickle_groups(amount, large, medium, small):
    large_bags, medium_bags, small_bags = 0, 0, 0
    while amount > 0:
        if amount > large:
            amount -= large
            large_bags += 1
        elif amount > medium:
            amount -= medium
            medium_bags += 1
        elif amount > small:
            amount -= small
            small_bags += 1
        else:
            small_bags += 1
            amount = 0
    return (large_bags, medium_bags, small_bags)
```

We can then use it on all the different ingredients:

```
butter_bags = trickle_groups(total[0], [500, 250, 125])
egg_bags    = trickle_groups(total[1], [12, 10, 6])
flour_bags  = trickle_groups(total[2], [750, 500, 250])
sugar_bags  = trickle_groups(total[3], [600, 400, 200])
```

Bam almost all your code is gone!
After this you should want to do the same with your print statements.
Make a format for the three duplicate print lines, and put it in a function.

```
DISPLAY_FORMAT = '''\
{1} large bags of {0} needed.
{2} medium bags of {0} needed.
{3} small bags of {0} needed.'''

def display_bags(type, bags):
    print(DISPLAY_FORMAT.format(type, *bags))

# ...

print("Purchases needed: ")
display_bags('butter', butter_bags)
display_bags('flour', flour_bags)
display_bags('sugar', sugar_bags)
display_bags('eggs', egg_bags)
```

After this I'd recommend that you rearrange the way that you go from input to output.
Instead of manually looping, you can instead actually use a `for` loop.
To do this you need to make a lists to loop through, so ingredients and bag sizes.
After this you'd want to actually loop through them, with `zip` you can quite simply.
And then you want to put it in a function `main`, which you call if you're in the main function:

```
INGREDIENTS = ['butter', 'egg', 'flour', 'sugar']
CUPCAKE = [4, 0.1, 12, 14]
LEMON = [80, 4.5, 240, 300]
BAG_SIZES = [
    [500, 250, 125],
    [12, 10, 6],
    [750, 500, 250],
    [600, 400, 200],
]

def main():
    cup_in = int(input('How many cupcakes would you like? '))
    lem_in = int(input('How much lemon cake would you like? '))

    amount_cup = [x*cup_in for x in CUPCAKE]
    amount_lemon = [x*lem_in for x in LEMON]
    total = [x + y for x, y in zip(amount_cup, amount_lemon)]
    bags = [trickle_groups(a, b) for a, b in zip(total, BAG_SIZES)]
    print("Purchases needed: ")
    for ingredient, bag in zip(INGREDIENTS, bags):
        display_bags(ingredient, bags)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

You can also optimize `trickle_groups`, rather than looping until the amount is zero, you can instead find the amount of large bags you need, and the remainder with `divmod`.
Where you get the amount you need with the division, and you get the amount left with the modulo part.
I change it also to take any amount of bags, and so you should be able to get:

```
def trickle_groups(amount, bag_sizes):
    bag_sizes = list(bag_sizes)
    bag_sizes.sort(reverse=True)
    amount_bags = []
    for bag in bag_sizes:
        n, amount = divmod(amount, bag)
        amount_bags.append(n)
    if amount:
        amount_bags[-1] += 1
    return tuple(amount_bags)
```

Comment: I'm curious about the function name `trickle_groups`.  Did you come up with it?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes I did, if you have a better idea then I'm all ears!

Comment: Not yet. It reminds me of algorithms used to represent numbers in roman numerals.  But I don't know of a good name for that, either.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I choose mine as it was kinda how I learnt, probably wrongly, trickle-down economics. The; upper, middle and lower, class have a predefined sized glasses, but the upperclass are at the top of this glass pyramid, and the 'water' trickles down. But I'm sure there's a better name, as it's not doing the same thing, :)

Answer (score 10):

```
cupcake = [4, 0.1, 12, 14]
#[Butter, egg, flour, sugar]
```

The fact that you had to put a comment explaining what the four items are suggests its not clear enough on its own. Instead, build something to hold the four values; I'd suggest a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), as you don't need the facilities of a full class:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Ingredients = namedtuple('Ingredients', 'butter,egg,flour,sugar')

cupcake = Ingredients(butter=4, egg=0.1, flour=12, sugar=14)
```

Now you can access e.g. `cupcake.egg` too, and you get a nice printable representation.

---

```
cup_in = int(input('How many cupcakes would you like? '))
```

I'd suggest you put some validation around this input; see e.g. [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761).

---

```
amount_lemon = []
amount_lemon = [(x * lem_in) for x in lemon]
```

The list comprehension creates a new list, so the first line is redundant.

---

After that, you have a lot of duplication. There is nothing different in the *logic* between assigning bags of e.g. flour and butter, just a difference in the *values*. I would refactor this into a function that takes those values, e.g.:

```
bag_egg_small, bag_egg_medium, bag_egg_large = subdivide(amt_egg, [6, 10, 12])
```

Similarly there's a lot of duplication in the printing out; try to reduce duplication, as it means that if you fix a bug or improve the functionality, everywhere that uses it benefits.